# Vue Sortable + Draggable not working when input boxes strings are longer than the box size

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, draggable

I'm using Vue draggable with Sortable.js.
Pretty cool library for dragging/reordering items on a list.
I found a problem in it though, whenever I have a list of input elements and the text is longer than the input box, that specific input box does not drag and drop.

I've tried debugging it but couldn't find if the issue could be on the library or some input box event that I could override to fix it.

Here is a fiddle showing an example: https://jsfiddle.net/egmstvL7/

Snipped below. Any ideas?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  myArray:["This one drags ok","This one too","Well, this one too","and this","Everything else drags except inputs that have string longer than the element size"],
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.8.4/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.20.0/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  {{ message }}
  <draggable v-model="myArray" group="people" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false">
   <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id">
   
   <input type="text" v-model="element"></input>
   
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I find that it does work, but you need to grab the input field on the very edge (or outside in the div). Maybe it's a better idea to add some sort of "handle" to each field, and only trigger the draggable when using the handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, draggable isn't disabling text selection on the longer input, so you can disable it yourself.  Do that using a CSS class and the `pointer-events` property:

```css
.noselect {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Use a boolean to toggle this class on all inputs:

```js
data: () => ({
  lock: false   // This will toggle a class on all textboxes
  ...
}
```

Use `mousedown`, `mouseup`, and `blur` events to manage the toggle and apply the `noselect` class when `lock` is `true`:

```html
<input type="text"
  v-model="element"
  @mousedown="lock = true"
  @mouseup="lock = false"
  @blur="lock = false"
  :class="{ noselect: lock }"
/>
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    lock: false,
    drag: false,
    myArray:["This one drags ok","This one too","Well, this one too","and this","Everything else drags except inputs that have string longer than the element size"],
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  })
})
```

```css
.noselect {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <draggable
    v-model="myArray"
    group="people"
    @start="drag=true"
    @end="drag=false"
  >
    <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id">
      <input type="text"
        v-model="element"
        @mousedown="lock = true"
        @mouseup="lock = false"
        @blur="lock = false"
        :class="{ noselect: lock }"
      />
    </div>
  </draggable>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@1.8.4/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Vue.Draggable/2.20.0/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Actually this isn't great because the `mouseup` won't always be detected and blur can fail. Some small bugs using `mousemove` too, even while checking for a button.  Not sure if it can be done this way bug-free.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it using a simple class that sortable automatically adds to dragging elements, here's the simplest solution but thanks @Dan for the clarification.

```
.sortable-chosen > input{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```